# How ViewModel could catch exception not thrown by the above layer?

Tags: android, kotlin, exception, mvvm

Currently developing an Android application in Kotlin I decided to learn the MVVM pattern.

I'm in a situation where I have :

**Fragment --> ViewModel --> Controller --> Repository**

My controller only serves as a cache for the current session.

Currently able to contact my API, I wanted to handle potential exceptions that might occur such as "UnknownHostException", "SocketTimeoutException" and display a different message for each Exception.

**NB :** I used **retrofit 2.6.0** with **coroutines** to do the job

The steps to request contact to the API are as follows:

- The fragment subscribes to the viewModel variables
- The viewModel launches its "fetchCommandList" method where it launches a coroutine with a try/catch and asks the controller to return the list of commands.
- The controller calls the repository if necessary.
- The repository tries to retrieve the data in a try/catch block

And that's where my question comes in. If you've read correctly, my controller doesn't have a try/catch, however, if in the repository an exception is thrown, the viewModel catches it well and changes its LiveData which displays the specific message of the exception in the fragment.

I don't understand how the exception is able to "skip" the Controller layer and still arrive in the viewModel.

Below is the code for each layer, from the view to the model:

***Fragment part about error LiveData***

```
mviewModel.mErrorStatus.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        mbinding.fragmentCommandListRecyclerview.visibility = if (it != null) View.GONE else View.VISIBLE
        mbinding.fragmentCommandListErrorTextView.visibility = if (it != null) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
        mbinding.fragmentCommandListErrorTextView.text = it
    })
```

***ViewModel call to the controller***

```
fun fetchCommandList(){
    //TODO : contact the controller method tha will firstly check is in list & if not result ask the repository to retrieve it
    viewModelScope.launch {
        mProgressBar.postValue(true)
        try {
            mCommandList.postValue(CommandControllerMock.getCommandsList())
            mCommandActive.postValue(CommandControllerMock.getCurrentCommand())
        }
        catch (e: UnknownHostException) {
            //this exception occurs when there is no internet connection or host is not available
            //so inform user that something went wrong
            mErrorStatus.postValue(e.message)
        } catch (e: SocketTimeoutException) {
            //this exception occurs when time out will happen
            //so inform user that something went wrong
            mErrorStatus.postValue(e.message)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            //this is generic exception handling
            //so inform user that something went wrong
            mErrorStatus.postValue(e.message)
        }
        finally {
            mProgressBar.postValue(false)
        }

    }

}
```

***Controller getCommandsList called by the viewModel (NO TRY/CATCH)***

```
override suspend fun getCommandsList(): List<Command> {
        if(m_commandList.size <= 0){
            //Todo: replace by auth.userID
            //Todo : before return the result, check if a command is already active to set currentCommand
            val returnedList = m_commandRepository.getAllCommandByUser(USER_ID)
            returnedList?.let{
                m_commandList = it.toMutableList()
            }
            checkForActiveCommand()
        }
        return m_commandList
}
```

***Repository method calling the API endpoint***

```
override suspend fun getAllCommandByUser(idUser: String): List<Command>? {
    try {

        val response = apiService.getAllCommandByUser(idUser)

        if (response.isSuccessful) {
            return response.body()
        } else {
            throw Exception("not 200 code")
        }
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        //this is generic exception handling
        //so inform user that something went wrong
        throw e
    }
}
```

So if for example, I disabled Internet on my phone I received the following message due to UnknownHostException  :
"Unable to resolve host "MY_API_ADRESS" : No adress associated with hostname"

If I put a readTimeout of 1sec in OkHTTP I received the following message due to SocketTimeoutException :
"timeout"

**I just don't understand the part where I forget to throw the exception in controller but it still catch by the ViewModel .**

Comment: what is the point of having a try catch inside your repository and then inside the catch having `throw e` ?

Comment: I want to propagate the exception until the viewModel to handle the UI display in it.

The repository just have to give the exception to lower layers

Comment: so what purpose does the try catch serve if it's catching the excepting and throwing the same thing ? then your try catch is redundant

Comment: I think I doesn't know how exceptions work, for me, if I didn't do that in my repository, the exception would have been lost.

Comment: well, you can test it. write a function to throw an exception with a try catch like yours and then one without, see if they are different or the same

Comment: Thanks for your help :) !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is natural for suspended functions to propagates runtime exceptions to top caller, until it either hits a try and catch block or coroutine scope, which is then either handled by exceptionHandler or cause the app to crash.

So in your case, nothing is suspicious, and the try&catch with exception rethrowing in repository layer is unnecessary.

See Coroutines exception handling [doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/exception-handling.html)

Comment: So, if I understand well (sorry I'm not english), the exception will be "automatically" thrown until the top caller (my ViewModel here) ?

So I can delete the try catch in my repository but let the one in ViewModel ?

Comment: yes, and check exception handling in Coroutines doc, which I added in the comment

Comment: Thanks for your help !!